# Postgres server not starting on drbd + pacemaker

Tags: postgresql, cluster, ubuntu-14.04, drbd, pacemaker

I am trying to bring up the postgres server over ubuntu 14.04 with drbd and fiesystem.

Service state as below:

```
Last updated: Mon Mar 14 01:16:45 2016
Last change: Mon Mar 14 01:05:53 2016 via cibadmin on node1
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node2 (2) - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.10-42f2063
2 Nodes configured
5 Resources configured


Online: [ node1 node2 ]

 Master/Slave Set: ms_drbd [drbd_postgres]
     Masters: [ node1 ]
     Stopped: [ node2 ]
 Resource Group: database
     fs_postgres        (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started node1
     ip_postgres        (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started node1
     postgresql (ocf::heartbeat:pgsql): Stopped

Failed actions:
    drbd_postgres_start_0 (node=node2, call=367, rc=1, status=complete, last-rc-change=Mon Mar 14 00:55:56 2016
, queued=3798ms, exec=0ms
): unknown error
```

My cluster configurations as below:

```
node $id="1" node1
node $id="2" node2
primitive drbd_postgres ocf:linbit:drbd \
        params drbd_resource="db_disk" \
        op monitor interval="29s" role="Master" \
        op monitor interval="31s" role="Slave"
primitive fs_postgres ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem \
        params device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main" fstype="ext4"
primitive ip_postgres ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
        params ip="192.168.1.103" cidr_netmask="24" \
        op monitor interval="30s"
primitive postgresql ocf:heartbeat:pgsql \
        params config="/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf" \
        params pgctl="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_ctl" \
        params pgdata="/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main" \
        op start interval="0" timeout="120s" \
        op stop interval="0" timeout="120s" \
        meta target-role="Started"
group database fs_postgres ip_postgres postgresql
ms ms_drbd drbd_postgres \
        meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" clone-max="2" clone-node-max="1" notify="true"
colocation fs_on_drbd inf: fs_postgres ms_drbd:Master
colocation postgresql_on_drbd inf: database ms_drbd:Master
order postgres_after_fs inf: fs_postgres:promote postgresql:start
order postgresql_after_drbd inf: ms_drbd:promote database:start
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
        dc-version="1.1.10-42f2063" \
        cluster-infrastructure="corosync" \
        stonith-enabled="false" \
        no-quorum-policy="ignore"    node $id="1" node1
node $id="2" node2
primitive drbd_postgres ocf:linbit:drbd \
        params drbd_resource="db_disk" \
        op monitor interval="29s" role="Master" \
        op monitor interval="31s" role="Slave"
primitive fs_postgres ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem \
        params device="/dev/drbd0" directory="/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main" fstype="ext4"
primitive ip_postgres ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
        params ip="192.168.1.103" cidr_netmask="24" \
        op monitor interval="30s"
primitive postgresql ocf:heartbeat:pgsql \
        params config="/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf" \
        params pgctl="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_ctl" \
        params pgdata="/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main" \
        op start interval="0" timeout="120s" \
        op stop interval="0" timeout="120s" \
        meta target-role="Started"
group database fs_postgres ip_postgres postgresql
ms ms_drbd drbd_postgres \
        meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" clone-max="2" clone-node-max="1" notify="true"
colocation fs_on_drbd inf: fs_postgres ms_drbd:Master
colocation postgresql_on_drbd inf: database ms_drbd:Master
order postgres_after_fs inf: fs_postgres:promote postgresql:start
order postgresql_after_drbd inf: ms_drbd:promote database:start
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
        dc-version="1.1.10-42f2063" \
        cluster-infrastructure="corosync" \
        stonith-enabled="false" \
        no-quorum-policy="ignore"
```

Corosync configuration:

```
totem {
  version: 2
  cluster_name: postgresql
  transport: udpu
  interface {
    ringnumber: 0
    bindnetaddr: 192.168.1.0
    broadcast: yes
    mcastport: 5405
  }
}

quorum {
  provider: corosync_votequorum
  expected_votes: 2
  two_node: 1
}

nodelist {
  node {
    ring0_addr: 192.168.1.101
    name: node1
    nodeid: 1
  }
  node {
    ring0_addr: 192.168.1.102
    name: node2
    nodeid: 2
  }
}

logging {
  to_logfile: yes
  logfile: /var/log/corosync/corosync.log
  to_syslog: yes
  timestamp: on
}
```

DRBD config:

```
resource db_disk {
  device /dev/drbd0;
  meta-disk internal;
  syncer {
    rate 40M;
  }
  on node1 {
    address 172.16.1.101:7789;
    disk    /dev/sdb1;
  }
  on node2 {
    address 172.16.1.102:7789;
    disk    /dev/sdb1;
  }
}
```

I am not seeing any error message in logs but this one:

```
root@node1:/var/log# egrep 'ERR|WARN' syslog
Mar 14 01:06:48 node1 Filesystem(fs_postgres)[13266]: WARNING: Couldn't     find device [/dev/drbd0]. Expected /dev/??? to exist
root@node1:/var/log#
```

Comment: Does mounting the drbd device "by hand" work?

Comment: Also: Running your cluster with shared storage without fencing / STONITH puts your data at risk. I hope you know what you're doing...

Comment: I will setup up stonith once the cluster service is up. I have disabled it for the config part only. Mounting of drbd works manually. Even after changing primary secondary ..i can mount and connect to db on secondary node.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is an oder constraint needed, which assures that the mount of the filesystem waits until the drbd resource was promoted to primary sucessfully. Without that order constraint Pacemaker could try to mount the FS while DRBD is still in the secondary role, which is not allowed by drbd.

Try this:

```
order fs_after_drbd inf: ms_drbd:promote fs_postgres:start
```